# Add subproject to a maven project to be used in jooq-codegen-maven

Tags: java, maven, gradle, jooq

I have a Gradle project which has a sub-project named generator.
sub-project is added to my main project in gradle.setting file :

```
include 'generator'
```

my sub-project has a build.gradle file that defined as :

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
  compile("org.jooq:jooq-codegen:${gradle.ext.jooqVersion}")
  compile "srvg.libs:jooq_utils:1908-VBI-580.1.+"
}

sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there is no project artifact name or version or etc. Just defined the dependencies.

Now for any reason I have to convert this project to maven nature. I generate a pom for my main project but what about this sub-project?

I know I can add it as  a module to my main project but it does not work for me because my main projects packaging is Jar and should stay as is. but to have module for a project it should be Pom packaging.

At the moment I have added my sub-project to resources via a helper plugin:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>generator/src/main/java/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

1. what is the true way to add my sub-project to maven project? which is the exact behavior of gradle **include** command.
2. is current solution using helper plugin is true? and acceptable? because in my scenario:

I am using jooq generator, which has to read the generator strategy parameters from a class in my sub-project?

And if it is not true, what is the best practice?